# What does "Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone" mean?

Tags: android

"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone"

Comment: Please give (a lot) more detail. Add some code. Tell us what you're doing and what happens. Maybe even ask a question?

Comment: You should include any relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 10):

Have look at: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=600288. This workaround solved the issue for me.

Specifically, add `-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU` to eclipse.ini (or in my case it was eclipse-php.ini).

Thanks due to to "Luca" / Luca Tettamanti  for posting that.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I was getting the error with [RTC plugin](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_client_installation_p2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apperently, the class `com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone` couldn't be initialized. Maybe have a look in the error log? Is the class in your class path?

Comment: its not on a specific project the problem.i am working on mac osx version 10.5.8 and the last version of eclipse and i have on the Error log all this exception:

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone

Comment: I all the time get this message on my Error log "Could not create the view: Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone" this situation its bad each time when i try to open a class i get this message, what should i do to solve this problem??

Comment: fix it? I'm sorry, my crystal ball is in the shop currently.

Comment: yes thank you i follow the step of this similar question, the subject : “Eclipse” trouble message error appear constantly