# "Eclipse" trouble message error appear constantly

Tags: android, eclipse

I get this message all the time on my error log:

```
Could not create the view: Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone.
```

This situation its bad: each time when I try to open a class I get this message.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be not related to android, but to your Eclipse version and current platform.
In case it is relevant, the blog post "[`Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone Error`](http://dhelbert.blogspot.com/2010/07/could-not-initialize-class.html)" (by [Derek Helbert](http://www.blogger.com/profile/00289195007208465669)) could be helpful.
(But only for Eclipse 3.6 on MacOs)

> If you are having a serious pain trying to run Eclipse Helios in Mac OS x 10.5.8 and keep getting errors such as the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

> --or--

```
An internal error occurred during: "Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone error".
```

> Here is an easy solution:
>
> Edit `eclipse.ini` with your favorite text editor and add a line at the end "**`-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU`**".
>   It's inside **`Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`**.

---

> Another solution is the following:
>
> 1. Decompress the `com.ibm.icu_4.0.1.v20090822.jar` file in the `eclipse/plugins` folder to any directory you like.
>      If you cannot find the exact version, just decompress the `IBM ICU JAR` that's shipped with your version of Eclipse.
> 2. In that directory, open the file `com/ibm/icu/ICUConfig.properties`
> 3. Replace
>        `com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType = JDK`
>        with
>        `com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType = ICU`
> 4. Recompress the `com.ibm.icu_4.0.1.v20090822.jar` file in the `eclipse/plugins` folder with the modified file
>
> However, it has been pointed out that editing the jar makes it unsigned.

Comment: thank you very much!!, what i should do to arrange that "However, it has been pointed out that editing the jar makes it unsigned"

Comment: @Problem: try first the `eclipse.ini` solution. Then you can try to modify `com.ibm.icu_4.0.1.v20090822.jar` (with the inconvenience of having it not signed, meaning you will get a warning when starting Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

see this buddy:[What does "Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740194/what-does-could-not-initialize-class-com-ibm-icu-impl-javatimezone-mean)

Comment: thanks but is no answer there if you can give an answer it will be great i am new on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and fixed it with:

apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java